# Loop over a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to load the following array with 2 object in the below league model.

The array that I want to load:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        title: "Osdorp StraatVoetbal",
        location: "Osdorp",
        city: "Amsterdam",
        lat: 52.3599,
        lon: 4.7891,
    },
    {
       title: "Slotervaart StraatVoetbal",
       location: "Slotervaart",
       city: "Amsterdam",
       lat: 52.3562,
       lon: 4.8273,
    }
];
```

The League model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LeagueSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    location: String,
    city: String,
    lat: Number,
    lon: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('League', LeagueSchema);
```

I am using the following function to load the array, but getting TypeError.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const League = require('../models/league');
const leagues = require('./leagues');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/footballeagues', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', ()=>{
    console.log("Mongoose Database connected")
});

const seedDB =  async() => {
    leagues.forEach( async (i)=>{
        const seedLeague = new League({
            title : `${leagues[i].title}`,
            location : `${leagues[i].location}`,
            city: `${leagues[i].city}`, 
            lat: `${leagues[i].lat}`,
            lon: `${leagues[i].lon}`
        })
        await seedLeague.save();
    })
}

seedDB().then( ()=>{
    mongoose.connection.close;
    //console.log('connection closed')
})
```

Could someone please help and advise me how to fix the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your code expects an array index as the parameter to your `forEach()` callback, but what it actually receives is the array value.

Here is working code that will solve your issue:

```js
    const seedDB =  async() => {
        leagues.forEach( async (element)=>{
            const seedLeague = new League({
                title : `${element.title}`,
                location : `${element.location}`,
                city: `${element.city}`, 
                lat: `${element.lat}`,
                lon: `${element.lon}`
            })
            await seedLeague.save();
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked :)

Comment: @Zizo If this answer resolved your problem, you are able to [accept it as the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the checkmark to the left. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information) This will let others know this question has been solved.